# PID from pg_backend_pid () does not exist in pg_stat_activity

Tags: postgresql, python

I have a software written in Python which accesses a postgres database. In order to allow several instances of the software, on one of the screens I need what is the connection identity so I check the `PID` by accessing the DB and retrieving it through the function `pg_backend_pid()`.

Everything works fine except that when I check the `PID` of the instance in `pg_backend_pid()` I get a `PID` number that does not exist in the `pg_stat_activity` table. In fact i can identify the `PID` number of my instance in the table but it is different than the number I received through the function `pg_backend_pid()`.

I would be happy if someone could help me understand why the `PID` I got from the function is different than what exists in the table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps pg_backend_pid is being run from a separate process that terminates once the backend pid is obtained? pg_stat is not a historical table - it only shows current pids. From the docs, " Process ID of the server process attached to the current session"

Comment: In other words, your software apparently creates new connections.